# I'm trying to parse and xml file with for each

Tags: php, xml, parsing

This is my xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Main Title</title>
        <link>https://mainlink.com</link>
        <description>Main Description</description>
        <language>en</language>
        <copyright>https://copyright.com</copyright>
        <ttl>5</ttl>
        <item>
            <title>Title One</title>
            <description>Description One</description>
            <pubDate>Mon, 07 Dec 2020 00:00:00 +1100</pubDate>
            <link>https://linkone.com</link>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Title Two</title>
            <description>Description Two</description>
            <pubDate>Fri, 04 Dec 2020 00:00:00 +1100</pubDate>
            <link>https://linktwo.com</link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

This my PHP

```php
<?php

if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('test.xml')){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}

foreach ($xml as $syn) {
    $t = $syn->item->title;
    $d = $syn->item->description;
    $p = $syn->item->pubDate;
    $l = $syn->item->link;

    echo $t.'<br>';
    echo $d.'<br>';
    echo $p.'<br>';
    echo $l.'<br>';
}

?>
```

This is what is displayed when I run the php

Title One
Description One
Mon, 07 Dec 2020 00:00:00 +1100
https://linkone.com

I need to echo each item so I get:

Title One
Description One
Mon, 07 Dec 2020 00:00:00 +1100
https://linkone.com

Title Two
Description Two
Mon, 07 Dec 2020 00:00:00 +1100
https://linktwo.com

Any suggestions would be appreciated, I've searched and tried with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your xml structure, correct loop is:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $syn) {

    $t = $syn->title;
    $d = $syn->description;
    $p = $syn->pubDate;
    $l = $syn->link;

    echo $t.'<br>';
    echo $d.'<br>';
    echo $p.'<br>';
    echo $l.'<br>';

}
```